# TreeList with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to javaScript and JQuery and trying to implement a TreeList with checkboxes.
My requirements are-

1) Expand and contract functionality

2) Selecting any child element, should higlight its child and all the parents untill the first UL element. There is no checkbox on parent

**Here is fiddle:**
[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vardhan22/CgRZR/)

I tried this also

```
$('#fieldsList :checkbox').change(function (){

    if (this.checked) {

          $(this).parent().addClass('checkedStyle');
          $(this).parentsUntil('#fieldsList', 'ul').addClass('checkedStyle');

    }
    else {       
          $(this).parent().removeClass('checkedStyle');         
    }
});

$('.viewList').on('click', function() {
        $(this).children('ul.details').slideToggle();           
});
```

Issues i am facing with my way:

a) Clicking on any of the child elements of outer li (A,B), also doing the slideToggle for that element. like clicking A1,A2,A21 any of them doing it

b) Not able to perform coloring of all parents. Whatever i am trying, it colors all the elements.

Need help

Comment: when you want to expand and contract elements?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/CgRZR/2/ is this you want

Comment: I want to toggle child elements. Like if A is clicked, A1,A2,A3,A4 should expand and contract, when A2 clicked A21,A22 should expand and contract.
And, for highlighting, i want when A21 clicked, A2 and A should get higlighted

Comment: I want combination of these two : http://jsfiddle.net/fRxVs/55/ (but istead of checking the parents, i want higlighting the text, and also i do not want that if parents is checked, all child is checked) and http://jsfiddle.net/VNkM2/4/ . Seems easy, but not bale to combine as structure used in both are different.